# What level will your new character on destiny be if you have already completed one or two of them?

Tags: destiny

I have reached level 20 on warlock, if I create a new character what level will it start out as? and do I have to do the whole story over again?

Answer (score 10):

Each "new" character you create will be level 1 like before, and You will have to go through story missions again. there is a few "new" features you will have available to your new character, though.

Firstly, if your first character is level 15+ (yes, in your case), you will be able to switch between subclasses freely on your new character. EX. You could *start* as a Defender.

Second, all of your glimmer is shared between characters, so buying gear for your new character will be a bit easier.

Third, the Vault is shared between characters as well. if you got a nice item for a different class that you plan on building, go ahead and vault it for them!

And finally, weekly and daily missions are bound to the character, so you could effectively double and triple your strange coin/ascendant farm if you have all three characters strong enough.

Comment: One other nice thing about the shared vault is that your top level character will likely have loads of blue engrams that can be passed down so its not just if you have a nice item but you can pass on engrams that will decode to items in the lower level characters level range (not sure if there is a bottom limit). eg if my level 15 character dcodes a blue helmet engram they are likely to get a blue helment of approximately level 15 (might be a bit higher or lower). I knew about the vault being used to pass items but this engram trick hadn't occurred to me til a friend pointed it out. :)

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Each new character you create, regardless of class, starts over from the beginning again. Level 1, no gear, no skills.

Comment: Once you get any character to level 15, you can start future characters with the alternate class right away. Additionally you can join in higher level missions than that character has unlocked if you're not the fireteam leader and the actual leader has them unlocked (except for level restrictions on some missions)

Comment: Also you can of course pass on gear from other characters through the vault if you actually thought to keep hold of it.

Answer (score 0):

Every new character you make starts at level 1.  If you already have a character on that account that is at least level 15, you can have access to two subclasses initially instead of one (i.e. if you're a Hunter, you can do either Gunslinger or Bladedancer first, instead of just Gunslinger).  You still need to be at least level 25 on the character you are currently playing to unlock TTK subclasses though.